# Windows hangs on clicking/copying large MKV file

Tags: windows-explorer, cpu-usage, matroska

I have a 2.9GB MKV file, unzipped from a .RAR archive, that causes explorer.exe to take up 100% CPU when I select it by single clicking.  Also, when I attempt to copy and paste it, the copy dialog hangs on the "Discovering files" phase until I end the process.  It is also the only video file in the folder that lacks a thumbnail image from the video; it is simply a VLC icon.  However, it plays normally in the player.

I suspect somehow the file info got corrupted and Windows keeps trying to read it, but I don't know how or why, or how to fix it.  I downloaded it again from the source and extracted it again, didn't fix it.  After moving via cut and paste (which took unusually long), the problem persists.  I would think the size would not be an issue, as it is neither the largest nor the smallest file in the directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Don't think it's a file corruption. I've ran Process Explorer and looks like it has to do with a DVIX Device module. The only way to delete the file is by CMD Line

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that it has to do with thumbnail generation. Try renaming the file. You can also try deleting the `thumbs.db` file in that directory (it is marked as both hidden and system) and see if it clears up a corrupted thumbnail. Or install the [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) and disable thumbnail generation for `.mkv` during the install.

Note that there are a lot of weird rules for thumbnail generation, including not generating for files greater than a certain size in addition to files by type (i.e. `.mkv`) and by location (i.e. local hard disk or network server). K-Lite gives you access to some of these settings during install.

Comment: I thought it might be something about the thumbnail generation but I wasn't sure.  I've tried renaming it to no avail, and there is no thumbs.db file in the directory.  I have "show hidden files" enabled, and I also have unchecked "hide system files".  thumbs.db exists in other directories but not this one.

Comment: @Jeremy It sounds like a problem with the source file itself.  An easy fix is to encode the video file again.

Comment: "Easy" in terms of procedure, not time. =P